# Error Install : Microsoft Net Framework 4.6 is a required prerequisite (windows 8.1)

Tags: entity-framework-4, windows-8.1, regedit, prerequisites

I have the following problem, hoping that some of you can help me.

I have to release an update based on a program that requires Net Framework 4.6.2 (not on the machine).

I would need to install Net Framework 4.6.2 (do not restart the machine) and immediately install a program that requires the same Net Framework 4.6.2 as dependencies.

Then install everything without a PC restart.

The Net Framework version 4.5 is already on the machine.
Trying to install Net Framework 4.6.2 in offline mode the installation is successful but when I launch the program that requires Net tells me that the correct version of the Framework is not detected (img below) despite Net Framework 4.6.2 has been just installed (I guess because it requires a default reboot).

[image]

I noticed that the problem is related to the fact that at the end of the installation the key with the version of the Framework is not updated.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
    Version    REG_SZ    4.5.51641
instead of

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
    Version    REG_SZ    4.6.XXXXX

Does anyone know a way to avoid rebooting and allow my application to find the newly installed version of Net and then be able to install it all?

Thank you,